# Add a scrollbar to the inner div (nestd divs)

Tags: css, height, overflow

http://jsfiddle.net/9Sjvm/

I am trying to put a scroll bar and also limit the height of the `<div id="items">` to 2 rows, right now it keeps increasing with the number of `<span>`s in it. Tried adding
`overflow:scroll` to inner divs but none of them works, any workaround for this particular structure?  The number of `<span>`s is dynamic and it can grow.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: auto` works just fine. You just need also to add `max-height` on on your `#items`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Sjvm/2/)

```
#items {
    //display: none;
    margin-top: 24px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: auto;
    max-height:100px;
}
.item1 {
    display: block;    
}
```

Comment: With max-height, it looks much cleaner. Thanks!